# How to start writing at column 2, row 2

Tags: python, csv

If you have a write.row command:

```
writer.writerow(row)
```

in a for loop, how do you start the writing in the 2nd column, 2nd row? I'd like to place a header at column 2, row 1, and preserve whats in the 1st column

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume that you're header is a set of tokens of length `len(columns)` - 1:

```
for rown, row in enumerate(csv_file):
    if != 1:
        writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        cols = []
        for col in enumerate(row):
            cols.append(col)
            break
        cols.append(header) # append header cols
        writer.writerow(','.join(cols))
```